# How to add changed dts-file in kernel in Yocto?

Tags: kernel, yocto

How to add changed dts file  and add own configure kernel file (.conf)in Yocto project? What recipe should i change and how?

Comment: Generally, create an append or recipe that builds your (patched) kernel for the desired machine. I demonstrate quite a bit of it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mf0CtUXlryc) including a lot of mistakes, and the full explanations are to be found in the [kernel dev manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html)

Comment: Thank you. I have started to watch your videos but i haven't gotten to series 6 yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose I would create my own layer then add kernel bbhappend :

```
sources/meta-ziegfried/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-tn-imx_%.bbappend
```

for the recipe exact name you should specify your exact kernel recipe name instead of mine. To know the name you can do :

```
$ oe-pkgdata-util lookup-recipe kernel
```

Then create a sources/meta-ziegfried/recipes-kernel/linux/patchs/ directory and simply add your modification of dts within a patch :

```
$ cat sources/meta-ziegfried/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-tn-imx_%.bbappend

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/patchs:"

SRC_URI += " file://0001-add-ziegfried-modified-dts.patch \
       "
```

And voilà that will automatically add your dts in the kernel.

For the kernel conf regarding the yocto version you are using you can use kernel fragment :

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#creating-config-fragments

Comment: I compile kernel in Yocto by command "bitbake -c  linux-imx". What path should i create in my recept and where i should copy defconfig?

Comment: Is it tnormal that any kind of change to the devicetree is compiled extremely fast?

Comment: indeed it's normal because changes in device tree are only text to binary so nothing fancy here. If you want to verify that change were taken in account you can "uncompile" your dtb : dtc -I dtb -O dts your-dtb.dtb -o uncompiled.dts

Comment: It is weird that in my case patch is applied (I can even see changes in the work directory's file `tmp/work-shared/beaglebone/kernel-source/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-boneblack.dts`), but the end result i.e. dtb that comes with the image is not affected by the patch. As if kernel was snot compiled after the patching was done.

Comment: May be you have an out of kernel tree dts that is built instead? Give a go to the #yocto irc channel to fix your issue someone will help you there.

Comment: @YCN I managed to create the patch - it was a typo. And now patch is applied. However it does not work - device does not reboot even if I only change the device tree `model` inn the original `.dts`. Any idea why this could happen?